# Unable to solve a syntax error near WHERE in sqlite, android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a String with an SQLite statement that I would like to execute like this..

```
String query = "UPDATE Inventory SET ProductName =" 
+ product.getProductName() + ", InStock =" + product.getProductInStock()
+ ", CostPrice =" + product.getProductCostPrice() + ",SellingPrice =" 
+ product.getProductSellingPrice() + ", Description =" 
+ product.getProductDescription() + " WHERE rowid =" 
+ String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(rowId) + 1);

db.execSQL(query);
```

I have a POJO class called Product.
`rowid` is an inbuilt variable right ? I tried it in uppercase and it still didn't work.

I am getting the following error

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "WHERE": syntax error
```

Comment: What is `String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(rowId) + 1)`? Or what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @tomerpacific, the end part is a string, no need of that.

Comment: @forpas rowId is a string but it contains a number, I converted it to  number then added 1, later I converted it back to a string because it is a part of a string variable.

Comment: 1) It will be easier to find the problem if you print out the value of `query`.  Add it to the Question.  2) You should be using a `PreparedStatement` rather than using "string bashing" to construct the query.

Comment: (My bet is that the product description is a string, and that is messing up because you haven't put quotes around it in the SQL string bashing.)

Comment: @StephenC Yes, actually all the values are strings not just product description. I thought it would cause less trouble if all the values are of same type.

Comment: Ah! I had missed a semicolon for the sqilte statement, I added `+ ";"` at the end of the string and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are setting values to `text` columns without the use of single quotes.
This can be one of the problems of the code.
 
The recommended way of doing updates is by using [`ContentValues`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues) which is also [sql-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) safe:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("ProductName", product.getProductName());
cv.put("InStock", product.getProductInStock());
cv.put("CostPrice", product.getProductCostPrice());
cv.put("SellingPrice", product.getProductSellingPrice());
cv.put("Description", product.getProductDescription());
int result = db.update("Inventory", cv, "rowid = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(rowId) + 1)});
```

The variable `result` will contain the number of rows updated.
I'm not sure about that value:

```
String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(rowId) + 1)
```

but if you have tested it then fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't actually find out what the mistake is, but content values method is working well. I used the same `String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(rowId) + 1)` when I retrieved products from the database and it worked correctly, so that is not the problem I think.

Comment: Fine if it works. Use ContentValues instead of concatenating sql parts. It's easy and safe.